# How to move all source code over when it was on VisualSVN Server on Vista and migrating to Windows 7?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

[i asked on Stackoverflow but maybe this forum is more proficient in this matter:]

I had VisualSVN Server running perfectly on a Windows Vista machine, and then now it is to run Windows 7 on that same machine (installed on a new partition).

So now all the source code are in the repository on D: drive (it used to be on C:)

(Windows 7 will be C:, and the Vista will now become D:)

Can we just copy the D:\Repositories over as C:\Repositories, and then install VisualSVN Server on Windows 7 again and let it use C:\Repositories, and then all source code, all history (the diff and comment) will be available again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make your day, I tested this on a clone of our development machines, and it worked. All the information about the repository is stored within the file, including all the tags etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may also be interested in [`svnadmin hotcopy`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/hotcopy/) tool.  Check the SVNBook reference: [Repository Backup](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/maint/#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup)